# System.EmailException: SendEmail failed. CANNOT_UPDATE_CONVERTED_LEAD

Tags: apex

```
List<Opportunity > oppList = [SELECT id,name,account.id from Opportunity];

    for ( Opportunity opp : oppList)
    {
        System.debug(opp.account.id);
        List<Lead > leads = [SELECT id,name,owner.id,email FROM Lead WHERE ConvertedAccountId = :opp.account.id];
        If(!leads.isEmpty()){
            // Send Email to leads email adddress
            EmailTemplate templateId = [Select id from EmailTemplate where name = 'EmailTemplate3'];
            User leadOwner = [Select id,email,firstname,lastname from User where id = :leads[0].owner.id];

            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
            mail.setTemplateId(templateId.id);
            mail.setToAddresses(leads[0].email.split(':'));
            mail.setReplyTo(leadOwner.Email);
            mail.setSenderDisplayName(leadOwner.firstname + leadOwner.lastname);
            mail.setBccSender(false);
            mail.setTargetObjectid(leads[0].id);
            mail.setwhatId(leadOwner.id);
            mail.SaveAsActivity = false;
            List<Messaging.sendEmailResult> results = Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.severity.CONFIRM, ' Email sent successfully.'));
            system.debug(results);
        }
    }
System.EmailException: SendEmail failed. First exception on row 0; first error: CANNOT_UPDATE_CONVERTED_LEAD, Invalid targetObjectId 00QO0000002Cx1BMAS: []
```

i get this error while trying to send an email. The lead is converted. Is it `setTargetObjectid` property that is causing error.
Is there any workaround.

Comment: Is your code called from trigger ?Could you share that as well

Comment: No i am running from execute anonymous apex window. I will later run it as scheduled apex code.

Comment: Can you add query filter with isconverted=false .You cant use converted Lead for this process

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that Target Object Id is causing it, since Lead is converted. You should be able to get ConvertedContactId from the lead and use it as a TargetObjectId to avoid this error.